# Present a view modally from the appDelegate swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have an NStimer in my AppDelegate,when the interval of time chosen has passed the application needs to present a viewcontroller modally from the selector's timer in the AppDelegate.Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: why are you doing it in appdelegate?

Comment: because the app has multiple views and I need the timer to not get destroyed if the user is not in  the view where the timer is set

Comment: what you mean by you have a timer? A view doesn't get destroyed regardless how long it is. Edit your question to show your storyboard.

Comment: I didn't say that the view get destroyed but I sait that the timer won't work if the user isn't in the viewcontroller where the timer is set. I need the timer to work on all the viewcontrollers

Comment: so have a main view of a viewcontroller, and add a timer in there. Then do whatever it is required of you to do, and present the specific view you want based on your logic. As far as a know, AppDelegate can only display your intended root view, but not presented modally.

Answer (score 0):

AppDelegate do not manage a view. You should present a ViewController modally in the first view controller that gets put on screen.

Comment: I have multiple view and not only one view